# How to change background-image opacity after .animate() in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am working with jQuery `animate(` function and it contains the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $("#animate1").fadeIn('slow').animate({
            'margin-left': '150px',
            'margin-bottom': '50px'
        }, 2000).fadeOut();

        $("#animate1").fadeIn('slow').animate({
            'margin-bottom': '0px',
            'margin-left': '-140px'
        }, 2000).fadeOut();
    }, 300);
});
```

```html
<div style="background-image:url('img/sofa.jpg');">
    <div id="animate1">
        <img src="img/chotu.png" style="height:200px; width:200px;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to change my `background-image` opacity as follows:

```
$("#animate1").fadeIn('slow').animate({
    'margin-left': '150px',
    'margin-bottom': '50px'
}, 2000)./* change bg-opacity here */.fadeOut();
```

Is it possible? I simply want to change my background image opacity after my first animate function.

Comment: You can't affect the opacity of the background directly. You can only change the `opacity` of the entire element. Also, isn't changing the opacity of an element's background at the same instance you fade that element out completely redundant?

Comment: You can use a pseudo element see https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-change-a-css-background-images-opacity

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div id="bg"></div>
    ...
</body>
```

You can make it as wide as the page using CSS:

```
#bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And then animate it's properties.

```
$('#bg')
    .animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
        $(this)
            .css({'background-image': 'url(1.jpg)'})
            .animate({opacity: 1});
    });
```

You can get a similar effect by fading the image opacity to 0, then change the background image, and finally fading the image back in again.

You could get more of a crossover effect, by having a second background div on top of this one, which you can then fade in.